# Systemd causing shutdown to hang

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, systemd

I have Ubuntu 17.10 installed on a Dell XPS 15 using Nvidia proprietary drivers (384.98). The shutdown process can sometimes take up to ten minutes and sometimes not shutdown at all.

I used a camera to record the shutdown messages as I couldn't see anything in the logs:

```
wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 90:21:06:96:c2:d1 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
systemd-shutdow: 33 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
systemd-journald[332]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Remounting '/' read-only with options 'errors=remount-ro,data=ordered'.
EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p1): remounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
systemd-shutdown[1]: Remounting '/' read-only with options 'errors=remount-ro,data=ordered'.
EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p1): remounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
kvm: exiting hardware virtualization
psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1
reboot: Restarting system
reboot: machine restart
ACPI MEMORY or I/O RESET_REG.
```

The major hang appears after wlp2s0 deauthenticates, and the first systemd-shutdow message takes up to 10 minutes to appear.

Is this a systemd problem? What could be causing the 33 output lines to be suppressed?

Comment: I only can propose you a workaround for the shutdown time; In `/etc/systemd` edit the `system.donf` file and uncomment the following line and change its parameter to a small seconds amount `#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s` to example `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s`, but this will leave the tasks really only 10 seconds to finish up their business.